# Grid layout in Java

Tags: java, open-source, graph, grid-layout

I am looking for OpenSource library with simple realization of Grid layout for graph in Java. Does somebody know such kind of library?

Comment: Can you say just a bit more about what you need? Would something like Graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/), which takes an input file and generates images, work for you?

Comment: I need a code of Grid layout algorithm in Java. Which I can edit and create my own layouting algorithm based on it.

Comment: Verticies and edges should be my inputs , and coordinates of verticies should be an outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 libs: [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/) and [Jdigraph](http://java.net/projects/jdigraph/).

And i choose Zest, because it's code more clearer.